# Query Store System View JOINs

Tags: sql-server, query, view, query-store

In SQL Server 2016, is there an optimal/correct way to JOIN sys.query_store_query_text and sys.query_store_query (joinable using query_text_id) with sys.query_store_runtime_stats?  I don't see any obvious common ID columns and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS doesn't help either.  I'm trying to beef up a simple querystore text search query to include usage and performance detail from the runtime_stats view.

Here's what I'm using currently, which works fine to identify queries containing a search string:

```
DECLARE  @SearchString NVARCHAR(100)=''
SELECT q.query_id, q.query_text_id, t.query_sql_text, object_name(q.object_id) AS parent_object, q.last_execution_time
FROM sys.query_store_query_text t JOIN sys.query_store_query q
   ON t.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
WHERE t.query_sql_text LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

I want to add a handful of the stats from sys.query_store_runtime_stats to this, if it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

A "query" one or more "plans", linked by [sys.query_store_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Each "plan" has multiple rows in sys.query_store_runtime_stats.  If you turn on Profiler while running the built-in Query Store reports you can see lots of examples.  EG

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (@results_row_count)
    p.query_id query_id,
    q.object_id object_id,
    ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(q.object_id),'''') object_name,
    qt.query_sql_text query_sql_text,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_duration*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) total_duration,
    SUM(rs.count_executions) count_executions,
    COUNT(distinct p.plan_id) num_plans
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
    JOIN sys.query_store_plan p ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
    JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON q.query_id = p.query_id
    JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qt ON q.query_text_id = qt.query_text_id
WHERE NOT (rs.first_execution_time > @interval_end_time OR rs.last_execution_time < @interval_start_time)
GROUP BY p.query_id, qt.query_sql_text, q.object_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct p.plan_id) >= 1
ORDER BY total_duration DESC',N'@results_row_count int,@interval_start_time datetimeoffset(7),@interval_end_time datetimeoffset(7)',@results_row_count=25,@interval_start_time='2021-04-16 10:13:43.0578184 -05:00',@interval_end_time='2021-04-16 11:13:43.0578184 -05:00'
```